# Solving this recursive equations

Tags: combinatorics

I have these recursive equations in Combinatorics and I need to find $a_n$

\begin{align}
a_n & = 2b_{n-1} + 2c_{n-1} \\
b_n & = a_{n-1} + c_{n-1} \\
c_n & = a_{n-1} + c_{n-1} + b_{n-1}
\end{align}

I tried alot of ways and could not get an independent equation for $a_n$.

Comment: One can use Equation 2 to transform Equations 1 and 3 into a system in $a$ and $c$ only. Did you try this?

Comment: I managed to get this: $a_n = 4b_{n-1} + 2b_{n-2}$

Comment: Which seems clearly wrong. You might want to expand on the way you got this.

Answer (score 1):

From (1) and (2):
$$
b_n = 2b_{n-2} + 2c_{n-2}  + c_{n-1}\ \ \ \ \ \ (4)
$$

From (2) and (3):
$$
c_n - b_{n} =b_{n-1} \ \ \ \ \ \ (5)
$$

Now substitute $c_n$ from (5) to (4).

.

Answer (score 0):

Define: $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$ and so on. Write:
$$
\begin{align*}
a_{n + 1} &= 2 b_n + 2 c_n \\
b_{n + 1} &= a_n + c_n \\
c_{n + 1} &= a_n + b_n + c_n  
\end{align*}
$$
By the properties of generating functions:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{A(z) - a_0}{z} &= 2 B(z) + 2 C(z) \\
\frac{B(z) - b_0}{z} &= A(z) + C(z) \\
\frac{C(z) - c_0}{z} &= A(z) + B(z) + C(z)
\end{align*}
$$
We are just interested in the solution for $A(z)$ in the resulting linear system:
$$
A(z) = \frac{a_0 - (a_0 - 2 b_0 - 2 c_0) z - (a_0 - 2 c_0) z^2}
            {1 - z - 5 z^2 - 2 z^3}
$$
Next step would be split this into partial fractions, and expand the fractions. But the factors of the denominator are quite ugly.